# iOS:Design a WheelView ,similar to UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation, rotation

I wanna make a circle list View, which can show something in each cell(averagely separated part) of Circle. This feature looks like `UITableView` except the movement style. The bottom part of circle view is hidden . In this way , I can change the content of hidden cells just like sth done in the callback :`-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Currently,  I run into a problem : How to get triggered when the circle rotates. I need to continuously monitor the change of angle and then determine cells is show/hidden.

As I know, when `Tableview` is dragged, `contentOffset` is changed and `scrollViewDidScroll` is invoked accordingly. I wanna make a counterpart callback to detect the change of angle.  But I have not have a clear idea yet. 
Would you please help to enlighten me ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: if your view is sub class from UISCrollView, you could use UIScrollView delegate didScroll method to get the current CGPoint, and convert it into some kind of radians, so you can decide. But you have to write the algorithm. If not, add a pan gesture to simulate user scrolling

Comment: FYI, there are several open-source wheel carousels, such as [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel).  Apple also has WWDC 2012 sample code for `UICollectionView` that demonstrates circular flow layout.

Comment: @Wingzero . that's really good idea. I  also find a similar solution. http://bharath2020.in/tag/circular-tableview/ . What I did is to make it horizontally displayed.

Comment: good article! It reminds me of there is some sites having many custom views and animations, effects. like code4app (if you know the language) and maybe github, or google it:)

Comment: @ PetahChristian good sample. that's really what I need . My solution is to have a UICollectionView with one row . And calculate the element position in each cell .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With further investigation on iCarousel, Wheel/Inverted Wheel sample code fully meets my requirement . Hope it's helpful to anyone being stuck in the same problem.